# How can I wait a result of async function with q.js in another event handler?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, promise, kendo-upload

I have the next Javascript event handler:

```
 function eventHandler(e) {
        //doSomething 1...

        asyncFunctionWhichReturnPromise(data).then(function (data) {
              //doSomething 2...
              e.data = {
                  Id: data.Id,
                  Type: "Type" 
              };
        });
        //doSomething 3...
 }
```

So when I run the code "//doSomething 3..." performs before "//doSomething 2..." but since it's an event handler function I need to prepare the data at the "//doSomething 2..." code block before the next event will be raised. How can I do it with q.js (the promises library of Kris Kowal)?

**Important Additional information: Actually I need the block //doSomething 2... be performed before leave from the eventHandler because there are initialization of e.data which will be used on the next step - kendo ui upload will upload the data on the server.**

Comment: You absolutely cannot. `doSomething2` is always performed asynchronously, after control left the event handler. You will need to find a way to make kendo ui upload wait.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the `doSomething 3...` code inside of the callback function

```
 function eventHandler(e) {
        //doSomething 1...

        asyncFunctionWhichReturnPromise(data).then(function (data) {
              //doSomething 2...

              //doSomething 3...
        });
 }
```

If you'd prefer to make it more obvious that `doSomething 3...` should run afterwards, you can put it inside of a function

```
 function eventHandler(e) {
        //doSomething 1...

        asyncFunctionWhichReturnPromise(data).then(function (data) {
              //doSomething 2...

              doSomething3();
        });

        function doSomething3() {
              //doSomething 3...
        }
 }
```

Comment: As I understand it - `//doSomething 2...` is also some asynchronous function. If so, then move `//doSomething 3...` into the callback of that function.